# React - Merging two Component Values

Tags: reactjs

Building a simple ToDo list app in ReactJS. This page is where an existing task can be edited:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {PageLayout} from "../components/page-layout";

import {useParams, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import TaskDataService from "../services/TaskService";
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import FadeIn from 'react-fade-in';
import UserDataService from "../services/UserService";

export const Task = props => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const initialTaskState = {
        id: null,
        familyId: "",
        userId: "",
        ownerId: "",
        ownerName: "",
        title: "",
        description: "",
        completed: false,
        dueDate: new Date()
    };
    const [currentTask, setCurrentTask] = useState(initialTaskState);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
    const [currentMember, setCurrentMember] = useState(null);
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(-1);

    const getTask = id => {
        TaskDataService.get(id)
            .then(response => {
                setCurrentTask(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveMembers();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (id)
            getTask(id);
    }, [id]);

    const handleInputChange = event => {
        const {name, value} = event.target;
        setCurrentTask({...currentTask, [name]: value});
    };

    const setActiveMember = (member, index) => {
        setCurrentMember(member);
        setCurrentIndex(index);
    };

    const retrieveMembers = () => {
        UserDataService.listMembers()
            .then(response => {
                setMembers(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    };

    const updateCompleted = status => {
        var data = {
            id: currentTask.id,
            userId: currentTask.userId,
            title: currentTask.title,
            ownerId: currentMember.userId,
            ownerName: currentMember.firstName,
            description: currentTask.description,
            completed: status,
            dueDate: currentTask.dueDate
        };

        TaskDataService.update(currentTask.id, data)
            .then(response => {
                setCurrentTask({...currentTask, completed: status});
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    };

    const updateTask = () => {
        TaskDataService.update(currentTask.id, currentTask)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                setMessage("The task was updated successfully!");
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    };

    const deleteTask = () => {
        TaskDataService.remove(currentTask.id)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                navigate("/tasks");
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    };

    return (
        <PageLayout>
            <FadeIn>
                <div className="list row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        {currentTask ? (
                            <div className="edit-form">
                                <h4>Task</h4>
                                <form>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="title" class="form-label">Title</label>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            className="form-control"
                                            id="title"
                                            name="title"
                                            value={currentTask.title}
                                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="description" class="form-label">Description</label>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            className="form-control"
                                            id="description"
                                            name="description"
                                            value={currentTask.description}
                                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="dueDate" class="form-label">Due Date</label>
                                        <DatePicker
                                            onChange={date => handleInputChange({
                                                target: {
                                                    value: date.toISOString().split("T")[0],
                                                    name: 'dueDate'
                                                }
                                            })}
                                            name="dueDate"
                                            dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
                                            value={currentTask.dueDate.toString().split("T")[0]}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="status" className="form-label">
                                            <strong>Status:</strong>
                                        </label>
                                        {currentTask.completed ? " Done" : " Not Done"}
                                    </div>
                                    <ul className="list-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="owner" className="form-label">Task Owner</label>
                                        {members &&
                                            members.map((member, index) => (
                                                <li
                                                    className={
                                                        "list-group-item " + (index === currentIndex ? "active" : "")
                                                    }
                                                    onClick={=> setActiveMember(member, index)}

                                                    key={index}
                                                >
                                                    {member.firstName} {member.lastName}
                                                </li>
                                            ))}
                                    </ul>
                                    <div className="col-md-6">
                                        {currentMember ? (
                                            <div>
                                            </div>
                                        ) : (
                                            <div>
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </div>
                                </form>

                                {currentTask.completed ? (
                                    <button
                                        className="badge text-bg-warning mr-4"
                                        onClick={() => updateCompleted(false)}
                                    >
                                        Not Done?
                                    </button>
                                ) : (
                                    <button
                                        className="badge text-bg-primary mr-2"
                                        onClick={() => updateCompleted(true)}
                                    >
                                        Done!
                                    </button>
                                )}

                                <button className="badge text-bg-danger mr-2" onClick={deleteTask}>
                                    Delete
                                </button>

                                <button
                                    type="submit"
                                    className="badge text-bg-success"
                                    onClick={updateTask}
                                >
                                    Update
                                </button>
                                <p>{message}</p>
                            </div>
                        ) : (
                            <div>
                                <br/>
                                <p>Please click on a Task...</p>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </FadeIn>
        </PageLayout>
    );
};
```

My problem is with the member selection piece, where you can change ownership of the task:

```
<ul className="list-group">
                                            <label htmlFor="owner" className="form-label">Task Owner</label>
                                            {members &&
                                                members.map((member, index) => (
                                                    <li
                                                        className={
                                                            "list-group-item " + (index === currentIndex ? "active" : "")
                                                        }
                                                        onClick={=> setActiveMember(member, index)}
    
                                                        key={index}
                                                    >
                                                        {member.firstName} {member.lastName}
                                                    </li>
                                                ))}
                                        </ul>
```

...and the function where we actually update the task:

```
const updateTask = () => {
            TaskDataService.update(currentTask.id, currentTask)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    setMessage("The task was updated successfully!");
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
        };
```

Selecting a new owner from the list did not actually change the ownerId/ownerName value in the task. I have figured out that this is because the new owner values live in currentMember, while the task information lives in currentTask - so I need to figure out how to get information from the updated currentMember into the proper fields in currentTask. I've monkeyed around with configurations but can't find a way to do this. Any advice?

Comment: You're code is not reproducible because of the DataService stuff, can you make a working example with dummy data here? https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The key was to define the task structure in a variable so I could specify from where the ownerId value would be pulled.

Original:

```
const updateTask = () => {
        TaskDataService.update(currentTask.id, currentTask)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                setMessage("The task was updated successfully!");
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    };
```

Updated:

```
const updateTask = () => {
        var data = {
            id: currentTask.id,
            userId: currentTask.userId,
            title: currentTask.title,
            ownerId: currentMember.userId,
            ownerName: currentMember.firstName,
            description: currentTask.description,
            dueDate: currentTask.dueDate
        };

        TaskDataService.update(currentTask.id, data)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                setMessage("The task was updated successfully!");
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    };
```